# Maven JAXB2 plugin fails to process bindings file

Tags: java, spring-boot, jaxb, wsdl, jaxb2-maven-plugin

How to make it recognize bingings file and then generate java classes from wsdl?

**pom**

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.14.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <generatePackage>com.example.demo.schema.gbg</generatePackage>
                    <generateDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</generateDirectory>
                    <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
                    <schemaIncludes>
                        <include>*.wsdl</include>
                    </schemaIncludes>
                    <bindingDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/bindings/</bindingDirectory>
                    <bindingIncludes>*.xml</bindingIncludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

**jaxb-bindings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<jaxws:bindings
        xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <!-- Name the package consistently (don't use wsdl URI domain name) -->
    <jaxws:package name="com.id3global"/>
    <!-- Use 'wrapper style rules' to produce Java names - no I don't know what it means either -->
    <jaxws:enableWrapperStyle>true</jaxws:enableWrapperStyle>
    <!-- Disable generation of asynchronous send/receive methods - might be fun for later though :) -->
    <jaxws:enableAsyncMapping>false</jaxws:enableAsyncMapping>

    <!-- Do not generate Element properties - they collide with the type namespace in Java,
        and yes, *all* this boilerplate is required for wsimport to apply the setting correctly -->
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
               xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" elementFormDefault="qualified"
               xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
               attributeFormDefault="unqualified" jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc" jaxb:version="2.1">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
                <jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false">
                    <xjc:serializable/>
                </jaxb:globalBindings>
            </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:schema>

</jaxws:bindings>
```

**Console:**

```
 org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; not an external binding file. 
The root element must be {http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb}bindings but it is {http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws}bindings
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you missing jaxb namespace declaration? Add `jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb` as shown in example below.

Also can you move the JAXWS-element inside of JAXB-element. Something like.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.1" jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc annox">
    <jaxws:bindings xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws">
    </jaxws:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```